# There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause-SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS. What I am trying to do. I have some text files in a folder. I want to get data from those files and load into sql server. I am using Script Task. Here's my code.

```cs
public void Main()
{
string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
try
{

//Declare Variables
string SourceFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolder"].Value.ToString();
string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();
string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
string ArchiveFolder = Dts.Variables["User::ArchiveFolder"].Value.ToString();
string ColumnsDataType = Dts.Variables["User::DataType"].Value.ToString();
string SchemaName = Dts.Variables["User::SchemaName"].Value.ToString();
//string ColumnList = "";

SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)
       (Dts.Connections["PLEGO.OwyheePrac1"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

//Reading file names one by one
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolderPath, "*" + FileExtension);
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{

//Writing Data of File Into Table
string TableName = "";
int counter = 0;
string line;
string ColumnList = "";

//MessageBox.Show(fileName);

System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
if (counter == 0)
{
ColumnList = "[" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "],[") + "]";
TableName = (((fileName.Replace(SourceFolderPath, "")).Replace(FileExtension, "")).Replace("\\", ""));
string CreateTableStatement = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[" + SchemaName + "].";
CreateTableStatement += "[" + TableName + "]')";
CreateTableStatement += " AND type in (N'U'))DROP TABLE [" + SchemaName + "].";
CreateTableStatement += "[" + TableName + "]  Create Table " + SchemaName + ".[" + TableName + "]";
CreateTableStatement += "([" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "] " + ColumnsDataType + ",[") + "] " + ColumnsDataType + ")";
SqlCommand CreateTableCmd = new SqlCommand(CreateTableStatement, myADONETConnection);
CreateTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//MessageBox.Show(CreateTableStatement);

}
else
{
string query = "Insert into " + SchemaName + ".[" + TableName + "] (" + ColumnList + ") ";
query += "VALUES('" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "')";

// MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

counter++;
}

SourceFile.Close();
//move the file to archive folder after adding datetime to it
File.Move(fileName, ArchiveFolder + "\\" + (fileName.Replace(SourceFolderPath, "")).Replace(FileExtension, "") + "_" + datetime + FileExtension);
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
// Create Log File for Errors
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::LogFolder"].Value.ToString()
+ "\\" + "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
{
sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}

}

}
```

I am getting this error:

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause.

I think this is because in source file. some rows has null values. Below is the example

```
ID, Name, LastName,ContactNumber
1,'abc','yuy',09090
2,,'wxz','4535
3,,,'7565
```

Comment: Warning, your code is **dangerously** open to injection. Never inject unsanitised strings (`'[' + TableName + ']'` is not sanitised) into a statement, and *always* use parameters where needed.

Comment: The error, however, is telling you the problem, there are fewer columns in the `INSERT` portion of your `INSERT` than there is in the `VALUE` clause. For example `INSERT INTO T (Col1) VALUES ('Value1','Value2');` would produce the same error.

Comment: yeah, I got you. But the problem is I am getting the columns and data dynamically. And I have no clue how to fix it

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel here, SSIS has built in functionality that easily handles nulls or anything else a flat file can throw at you, the only thing it doesn't do is dynamic columns. These files are going to database tables so the destination can't be dynamic unless you are creating those destination tables on the fly too? If you have a set amount of file types then you could create folder enumerators and use a dynamic flat file source

Comment: In addition to the SQL issues your CSV file reading code has the broken assumption that CSV records will only ever span a single line. Have a read through [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for CSV Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) to see how fields are encoded and can span multiple lines. Also have a look into the DelimitedFileSource2008 component which handles dynamic CSV/PSV/TSV files with ease and write a Programmatic SSIS Package around it that creates the destination table from the file columns and then bulk inserts the data into it.